# How to represent user input when creating filter in Drupal Views for number range?

Tags: view, drupal, filtering

Sorry for being a newb, but I can't find the answer to this question after hours of looking. I need to allow users to filter through other users' profile information and have multiple fields such as age, height, etc, which are number fields. I want them to be able to find, say, all users who are between the age of 23 and 27. I can't just leave the "value" empty, so I need to know what to write there so that the end user can input their own value (i.e., "23" for "Min", "27" for "Max" fields) and with the "greater than or equal to" and "less than or equal to" operators should get the results they're looking for. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.[The screen in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gUjQ.jpg)

I tried using what I thought was the proper syntax, specifically "{{ value }}" and "{{ input }}", and just leaving that field blank when creating the filter.

[EDIT]: Sorry - Using Drupal 10, I believe. And I'm not sure this is clear from my post, but I'm trying to create a grouped filter. Not sure if that is the way to go about it. The result in preview just looks like two check boxes labeled "Min" and "Max", so that's confusing me as well.

Answer (score 0):

So...

I think I found my answer while waiting for someone to answer. I just created it as a normal (not grouped) filter and left the field blank.

Thanks anyway!